# Python path conflict

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7, virtualhost

I am planning to run two sites in a single server. Let say it as example1.com and example2.com. The simplified code base structure is as below.

```
example1.com

/data/common/common.py
/data/common/site/example1.com/site.py

example2.com

/data/common/common.py
/data/common/site/example2.com/site.py
```

Some times the example1.com import site.py wrongly from /data/common/site/example2.com/site.py because it contains both /data/common/site/example2.com and /data/common/site/example1.com in sys.path coming from common.py.

So trying to fix the path issue in common folder is a huge task as it contains 1000 of files.So i want to fix it in apache level.Is there a way i can set the example1.com virtual host to deny permission for /data/common/site/example2.com folder and example2.com virtual host to deny permission for /data/common/site/example1.com folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Are they not in separate virtual envs?

Comment: @Sayse no they are not in seperate virtual env

Comment: @e4c5 common.py is inside common folder.

Comment: Well there in lies the problem, don't try to force everything into the same environment, keep them separate and then this becomes a non-issue